# Why doesn't nav height automatically adjust to its content?

Tags: html, css

I have the following `nav` element in my html:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="content/unternehmen.html">Unternehmen</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
        <li><a href="content/leistungen.html">Leistungen</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
        <li><a href="content/referenzen.html">Referenzen</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
        <li><a href="content/news.html">News</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
        <li><a href="content/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My CSS design for the normal size of the homepage looks like this:

```
nav {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #61625B;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

    nav ul {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 70%;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0 15%;
        display: flex;
        margin: 0;
    }

    nav li {
        width: 125px;
        text-align: center;
    }

.navunderline {
    width: 125px;
    height: 0;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    background-color: #DAD9D7;
    transition: 500ms;
}

nav a {
    color: #DAD9D7;
}

    nav a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

nav li:hover .navunderline {
    height: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

This works perfectly fine. However, for smaller displays, I want to display the navigation items vertically, so I have the following CSS code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    nav {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #61625B;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        overflow: visible;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

        nav ul {
            height: auto;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            list-style: none;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 0;
        }

        nav li {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

    .navunderline {
        display: none;
    }

    nav li:hover {
        background-color: #8b131f;
    }
}
```

Here is the problem: The `height` of my `nav` element in this case is set to auto. If I set a fixed value, it displays correctly. However, I want to adjust it automatically to the size of the content. Problem is, that with height set to auto, the `nav` element completely vanishes to zero height. How can I set it, so it's height is adjusted by the elements it contains?

```css
nav {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #61625B;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

    nav ul {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 70%;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0 15%;
        display: flex;
        margin: 0;
    }

    nav li {
        width: 125px;
        text-align: center;
    }

.navunderline {
    width: 125px;
    height: 0;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    background-color: #DAD9D7;
    transition: 500ms;
}

nav a {
    color: #DAD9D7;
}

    nav a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

nav li:hover .navunderline {
    height: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    nav {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #61625B;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        overflow: visible;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

        nav ul {
            height: auto;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            list-style: none;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 0;
        }

        nav li {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

    .navunderline {
        display: none;
    }

    nav li:hover {
        background-color: #8b131f;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="content/unternehmen.html">Unternehmen</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
        <li><a href="content/leistungen.html">Leistungen</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
        <li><a href="content/referenzen.html">Referenzen</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
        <li><a href="content/news.html">News</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
        <li><a href="content/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you add a demo link?

Comment: @HarishSharma done, edited OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem is, that with height set to auto, the nav element completely vanishes to zero height. How can I set it, so its height is adjusted by the elements it contains?

This problem is occurring because your `ul` element has `position: absolute`. Because of this property, your `ul` element is no longer "living" in the same space of the normal document layout.

To fix this, you can add this to your media query:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  nav ul {
    position: relative;
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #61625B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 70%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 15%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

nav li {
  width: 125px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navunderline {
  width: 125px;
  height: 0;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  background-color: #DAD9D7;
  transition: 500ms;
}

nav a {
  color: #DAD9D7;
}

nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav li:hover .navunderline {
  height: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  nav {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #61625B;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav ul {
    position: relative; /* Add this */
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navunderline {
    display: none;
  }
  nav li:hover {
    background-color: #8b131f;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="content/unternehmen.html">Unternehmen</a>
      <div class="navunderline"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="content/leistungen.html">Leistungen</a>
      <div class="navunderline"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="content/referenzen.html">Referenzen</a>
      <div class="navunderline"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="content/news.html">News</a>
      <div class="navunderline"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="content/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
      <div class="navunderline"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you...sometime you just look at something for so long, you don't see something obvious^^